# How to add cart to custom page?

Tags: magento2.3, shopping-cart

I have a custom page where users can fill out their e-mail to receive a quotation. I would like to add a column with a list of items currently in the shopping cart. How to achieve this?

When I Google for the above question, the only results I get are how to add custom content to the checkout page, which is exactly the other way around.

I am fairly new to Magento, these are the things I've tried:

`<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart" template="Magento_Checkout::cart.phtml" />`

or:

`<referenceBlock class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart" template="Magento_Checkout::cart.phtml" />`

Both options don't show anything. I even tried to add the full container contents from **checkout_cart_index.xml** from the **Magento_Checkout** module, but that doesn't seem right and of course I got a lot of reference errors.

Comment: are you using a module for the custom page?

Comment: Do you want to display just item list with add to cart button or you want to display other things as well like order summary , coupon box. If you wan to display just items with add to cart then you can just create a custom module with function of getAllVisibleItems and display items on .phtml file and add that block in custom page via xml.